# PHP increment to 10 digits number for 10000 times get inaccurate results

Tags: php

I have a script trying to increment value for 10000 times but it does not increment properly after certain numbers.

```
$number = 2147480001;
$number_length = 10;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++){ 
  $number++;
  $number = sprintf("%0".$number_length."d", $number);
  echo $number."\n";
}
```

The result returned like this:

...... 2147483645 2147483646 2147483647 -2147483648 -2147483647 -2147483646 ......

Can I know why it suddenly turns to negative value?

Comment: What is this `$number_length`?

Comment: $number_length is 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phenomenon you have encountered is called [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). Your integer value is stored in a memory cell with a fixed size (32 bits), so a limited range of integer values can be stored in that cell (from PHP_INT_MIN to PHP_INT_MAX). If you go beyound that borders, things start to break.

According to [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow):

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead.
>
> If the float is beyond the boundaries of integer (usually +/- 2.15e+9 = 2^31 on 32-bit platforms and +/- 9.22e+18 = 2^63 on 64-bit platforms other than Windows), the result is undefined, since the float doesn't have enough precision to give an exact integer result. No warning, not even a notice will be issued when this happens!

For one iteration, your `$number` becomes larger than PHP_INT_MAX constant, so it is converted to double. After that you immediately convert it back to integer, and get that "undefined result".

Comment: Thanks Andriy. Any idea how to achieve the correct increment after reaching the max integer?

Comment: @ShirleyKuanSF You can use [GMP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) or [BCmath extension](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php), both provide integers with infinite size. Or just use floating-point numbers (try this: `$number = sprintf("%0".$number_length."f", $number);`). But floating point numbers lack precision, so starting from some number you will get errors again

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

2147483647 is the largest value of a signed integer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647

Answer (score 0):

This

```
for ($i == 0; $i < 10000; $i++){
```

should be

`for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)`{

you should set the variable to `0` not check if it's equal to `0`

Also what is `$number_length` for?

Comment: Some people are just that way.  I just got downvoted having the same information as the upvoted answer; I just couldn't format because I was typing on a phone.  I also noted the undefined `$number_length` and it's uncertain effect on the padding of the `sprintf`.  I was going to fill out the answer with notated results of what was going on behind the scenes, but... not so inclined now.

Comment: FWIW, your answer may have been down voted because it was considered more appropriate for a comment-- "what is `$number_length` for?"

Comment: I just appended my comment on my answer since I was posting one anyway :). I was going to post my answer as a comment but I figured it should be considered as an answer since this is a clear bug. Thank you for the feedback @TimMorton

Comment: I'm sorry for the typing mistakes.